# convert TCP/IP to Address name on LAN network

Tags: tcp

I wonder if I can use TCP connection protocol or something similar to it to convert IP to Address name
ex:
192.168.1.10:8080    //convert this ip to for example >>
my.localpc.com        // or thomething looks like this

so Where I can start from 
I like if suggestions related to these lang.s (C# , Python , C++ , MATLAB)

### here is the story

"..

I was building an ROV for a competition and I used TCP IP to transfer date from PC to Raspberry PI but the IP always changes whatever I use fixed IP sometimes I have to change the TCP port then I'll change the port on the client program as well , so I asked myself if there is a way to call the ROV like http\myROV.com .. instead of 192.168.1.5:8080 .. which may change on several situations "

Thank you

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: It is not really a reasearch

Answer (score 1):

Anything that can access normal sockets functions directly should be able to use [`gethostbyaddr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521.aspx) or [`gethostinfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532.aspx).